# Customize Conditional Formatting in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm unable to create a rule in **Conditional Formatting** for this requirement. I was tried using this option "**Use a formula to determine which cells to format**" inside the rule but didnt get proper formulae.

**My Requirement**:

If I change the `Activity` value to `Completed` in column `A`  then accordingly the font color should be in (Sky blue) and font size is (10) in columns `B` and `C`.

If I change the activity value to `Delayed` in column `A` then the font color should be in (Red) and font size is (Default or no change) in columns `B` and `C`.

Also if I manually type to change the `Activity` type from `To Do` to `Completed` then the `Final Date` column field value should be automatically filled with the current or Today's date which is as on date.

What formulae I can use for this requirement? How?

[image]

Comment: Conditional formatting is simply that.  You can't add a value to a cell with it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the text format is easy to solve with Conditional Formatting, changing the cell's text to today's date requires VBA.

**1. Text format**

- Select cells B2:C10
- Create a conditional format with "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Enter this formula:

  ```
  =$A2="Completed"
  ```
- Click the 'Format' button and apply the blue text color and your desired font size.
- Repeat the steps using this formula:

  ```
  =$A2="Delayed"
  ```
- Apply the red font color.

**2. Enter today's date via VBA**

- Open the VBA editor with Alt+F11
- Double click the worksheet on the left hand panel where your Activity table is placed (i.e. Sheet1).
- Enter this code in the right hand code panel:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Value2 = "Completed" Then
          Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Date
      End If
  End Sub
  ```